# Intuition for conformal nets

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, higher-category-theory, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I was planning on reading the work of Arthur Bartels, Christopher L. Douglas and André Henriques on the 3-category of conformal nets as discussed in these papers: [Coordinate-free nets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2604), [Conformal blocks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8672), [Fusion of defects](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8263), [The 3-category](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00662) and [Dualizability](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03393).

I wanted to know how the structure of a conformal net arises from the physical notion of a conformal field theory.

Comment: What physical notion of CFT is your starting point?

Comment: So I'm familiar with the physicists approach and the definition as cobordisms of 1 dimensional complex manifolds (Segal's definition). Either of these would be good starting points for me.

Comment: I'm very very far from an expert on the subject but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_quantum_field_theory) might be helpful

Comment: You might find André Henriques' lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7328 useful